# .closest() not working when looking for H3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looking to find the value of the H3 within this block of text, `onclick`. I have tried the `closest` method but it's not working. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.companyBtn', function() {
  var ha = $(this).closest('.testTitle').val();
  alert(ha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 companyBtn" id="3543">
  <div class="strip">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle d-inline pr-2" style="max-width: 50px" src="/members/images/3543.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="strip_info seenIcon">
          <div class="item_title">
            <h3 class="testTitle" style="width:90%;font-size:1.1rem">Test Company</h3>
            <small class="d-block mb-3">  <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>  United Kingdom</small>
            <small class="badge badge-warning">Artist Managers</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The description and examples in  [closest() docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) should tell you it is not the correct tool for the job. Neither is using `val()` for content elements

Comment: Method `closest()` allows you to refer to the parents of the current selector, but you do the opposite. Chances are you want to use method `find()`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method looks for ancestors of the current node, and `h3` is a descendant of `.testTitle`. Replace `.closest()` with [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), which looks for descendants, and get the text content with [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.companyBtn', function() {
  var ha = $(this).find('.testTitle').text();
  console.log(ha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 companyBtn" id="3543">
  <div class="strip">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle d-inline pr-2" style="max-width: 50px" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/400/100/100.jpg?hmac=pvDsAYmMO0rcZJDGuhmCPDrPeCkJIkGR90-rqPYCMmw">
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="strip_info seenIcon">
          <div class="item_title">
            <h3 class="testTitle" style="width:90%;font-size:1.1rem">Test Company</h3>
            <small class="d-block mb-3">  <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>  United Kingdom</small>
            <small class="badge badge-warning">Artist Managers</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```